# how to Remove last last json record in azure logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

{
" Date": "12/02/2022 15:01",
"Product Code": "5057636582976207",
"Description": "12022 3XL 372 Da",
"Qty": "1",
"Pricing Inc. VAT": "12"
},
{
" Date": "12/02/2022 15:33",
"Product Code": "505763667606927",
"Description": "18939 L 090 ",
"Qty": "1",
"Pricing Inc. VAT": "33"
},
{
" Date": "12/02/2022 17:07",
"Product Code": "5057633566615660",
"Description": "18905 ONE ",
"Qty": "1",
"Pricing Inc. VAT": "10"
},
**{
" Date": "",
"Product Code": "",
"Description": "",
"Qty": "96",
"Pricing Inc. VAT": "1883.6"
}**
the problem is  price inc vat in last array will always change so cant use Replace()
any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use the Below Expression to fetch the specific result

```cs
// Use add & length expression add(length(outputs('Compose')),-1) to remove the no of values 

take(outputs('Compose'),add(length(outputs('Compose')),-1))
```

#### Follow the workaround

Here I am using your JSON payload and processed with it.

```json
{
    "result": [
        {
            " Date": "12/02/2022 15:01",
            "Product Code": "5057636582976207",
            "Description": "12022 3XL 372 Da",
            "Qty": "1",
            "Pricing Inc. VAT": "12"
        },
        {
            " Date": "12/02/2022 15:33",
            "Product Code": "505763667606927",
            "Description": "18939 L 090 ",
            "Qty": "1",
            "Pricing Inc. VAT": "33"
        },
        {
            " Date": "12/02/2022 17:07",
            "Product Code": "5057633566615660",
            "Description": "18905 ONE ",
            "Qty": "1",
            "Pricing Inc. VAT": "10"
        },
        {
            " Date": "",
            "Product Code": "",
            "Description": "",
            "Qty": "96",
            "Pricing Inc. VAT": "1883.6"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

#### Results

[image]